# How to dynamically set textview height android

Tags: android

In my application I need to set dynamic text to my textview so I want it to get resized dynamically. I have set:

```
<TextView

android:id="@+id/TextView02" 

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textStyle="normal"

android:layout_weight="1"

android:singleLine="false"

android:minLines="4" />
```

And from java code I am setting **text** of the **textview** at runtime..

My textview height is not going beyond 1 line and the text is getting cut. Can anybody please help?

Thanx in advance.
And from java code I am setting **text** of the **textview** at runtime..

My textview height is not going beyond 1 line and the text is getting cut. Can anybody please help?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: It would help us a lot if you could edit your layout code into your question.

Comment: I have edited layout code. Plz do see and reply me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your android textView use the following attribute and it will solve your problem:

android:inputType="textMultiLine"

For eg:

```
<TextView
    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
    android:minLines="4"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```

Comment: I agree, this don't fix the problem. The correct solution is to change layout_width to be an exact size, for example 200dp. In that way the attributes minLines and maxLines will be considered when computing the height of the TextView. This is clearly a bug in the TextView implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this, i do not know it will work or not...
First try to fix the width just a normal text view

Comment: like this  <TextView 
             android:layout_width="200dip"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it helps to solve your problem, but I had the same problem and my solution is to add \n in the string that will be set in the textview element in java:

```
views.setTextViewText(R.id.row_1_address, "streetname 1\n12345 city");
```